# how to show my data from database on 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just newbie in PHP. I started learning yesterday.

I have 1 problem to show my data from DB to my test PHP project.

I have data like :

```
| Class Room | Teacher | Pict |
| A1         | ABU     | 1.jpg|
| A1         | ABU     | 2.jpg|
```

before I ask, I did "select * from X group by teacher' and I get data like :

```
| Class Room | Teacher | Pict |
| A1         | ABU     | 1.jpg|
```

I want this data show on my site like :

```
| Class Room | Teacher | Pict           |
| A1         | ABU     | 1.jpg :: 2.jpg |
```

so, in this case I got stuck and I just need help to learn.

Comment: Your data base structure is not clear.attach print screen of your database table.

Comment: Show the code where u are currently stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Class Room, Teacher,  GROUP_CONCAT(Pict SEPARATOR '::') as Picsts
FROM X GROUP BY teacher
```

Comment: invalid use off group by read this https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/